# Windows Forms Designer can't find DLL

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a Problem with using Usercontrols from another Library.

I have a Project Solution in the Project Solution are two Projects (the Main Program and a Library) in the Library are my custom Usercontrols and some Objects which will be used from the Usercontrols. For example a custom List View which shows some informations from the Object that is given.

My Problems are:

1. that the Designer cant found the Library which I added over the Toolbox (choose elements...) and
2. that when I try to choose an Object instance (which should be shown) the designer says that it cant be found although the Object class is public.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: When projects are in the same solution, you don't need to add controls to toolbox yourself and the toolbox will be populated automatically and shows controls in a new group at top of the toolbox groups.

Comment: Don't add it to the toolbox.  It is risky in this scenario since that makes a copy of the assembly to a private folder that stores toolbox assemblies.  That copy can get very easily out of date when you make changes to the library project.  Just rely on the toolbox auto-populating itself after you build the solution.  Also make sure that the [AssemblyVersion] of the library project does not use wildcards.